# Obtaining ID of Sanic Session

Tags: session, twilio, sanic

I'm placing session data in the Sanic in-memory session using the following code:

```
app = Sanic.get_app()
Session(app, interface=InMemorySessionInterface())
request.ctx.session['foo'] = 'bar'
```

How do I access the ID associated with this session? I need to send the ID to Twilio using the render function with a template. Thanks.

Comment: Has anyone used sanic-session successfully with Twilio? If so, how did you manage to pass the session ID to Twilio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot comment on the Twilio integration as I have never used it, but you can access the session id from the session object:

```py
session_id = request.ctx.session.sid
```